# MBR no muestra Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Se que hay miles de posts con la misma duda en internet. Pero he probado todo lo que dicen y no lo consigo.

Tengo 2 discos SSD. He instalado Windows 10 en SDA (GPT) junto a una partición que viene de fábrica de Lenovo. Y Pop!_ (Ubuntu 18) en el SDB. Tengo dos problemas:
- El primero es que se inicia Ubuntu automáticamente sin mostrarme el GRUB por lo que tengo que encender el ordenador con la tecla shift pulsada para que me lo muestre.
- El segundo es que cuando se muestra el GRUB no me detecta Windows por lo que me hes imposible acceder a Windows actualmente.

Tengo mi BIOS en modo Legacy y Secure Boot desactivado.

No me importa reinstalar los SO otra vez. Solo quiero tener Windows en un disco y Ubuntu en el otro y que el GRUB me deje elegir entre ambos.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/q2NrCcy9N9/

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Instalaste Ubuntu desconectando el disco en el que tenías Windows 10? Si fue así deberías volver a ejecutar el instalador de Grub (`grub-install`) o un `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` con el disco de Windows conectado.

Comment: Tal vez la partición de Windows usa UEFI.  Si como es, no muestra cuando BIOS está en modo Legacy.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado. El problema fue que al instalar Windows en sda, me instaló los archivos de boot en sdb y cuando instalé el Pop, me eliminó esos archivos y es por eso que no detectaba Windows.

Lo que hice fue instalar Windows desconectando la segunda memoria y después instalar Pop conectando la segunda memoria.

Solucionado, GRACIAS!